# spring context doesn't load

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to load the context, but I get UnsatisfiedDependencyException
I can’t understand what is the reason, annotations and constructor in the service are supplied

DataJpaRepository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DataJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Visit, Long> {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    Visit save(Visit visit);

    Visit findByGuestId(long guestId);

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT v FROM Visit v WHERE  v.date BETWEEN :from AND :to")
    List<Visit> getBetween(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);
}


@Repository
public class VisitRepositoryImpl implements VisitRepository {

    @Autowired
    private DataJpaRepository dataJpaRepository;


    @Override
    public Visit get(long guestId) {
        return dataJpaRepository.findByGuestId(guestId);
    }

    @Override
    public Visit save(Visit visit) {
        return dataJpaRepository.save(visit);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Visit> getAll() {
        return dataJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Visit> getBetween(Date from, Date to) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(from, "fromDate must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(to, "toDate must not be null");
        return dataJpaRepository.getBetween(from, to);
    }
}
```

VisitService:

```
@Service
public class VisitService {

    private VisitRepositoryImpl repository;

    @Autowired
    public VisitService(VisitRepositoryImpl repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Visit save(Visit visit) {
        return repository.save(visit);
    }

    public List<Visit> getAll() {
        return repository.getAll();
    }

    public List<Visit> getBetween(Date from, Date to) {
        Assert.notNull(from, "fromDate must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(to, "toDate  must not be null");
        return repository.getBetween(from, to);
    }
}
```

I get Exception aused by:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'visitService' defined in file
>   [D:\JAVA\library-project\target\classes\com\java\library\service\VisitService.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.java.library.repository.VisitRepositoryImpl' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

main class also:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.java.library.repository")
@EntityScan("com.java.library.model")
@ComponentScan("com.java.library.service")
@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it spring boot? Show your main/configuration class also

Comment: added to description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add your repository package to @ComponentScan configuration

```
@ComponentScan({"com.java.library.service", "com.java.library.repository"})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add @Autowired annotation in VisitService class.

```
@Autowired
private VisitRepositoryImpl repository;
```

Comment: Yes. Realized it later.